# Restore WhatsApp chats on new phone but forgot the encryption password of my back up

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I am moving WhatsApp to a new phone.

After inserting 6 digits from the new phone I am logged out of my old phone. That is fine. Now the new phone ask for encryption password. I have no idea if that's ever been asked before.

I can click forget my password but https://faq.whatsapp.com/639067727894647 it's the new phone. It doesn't have my WhatsApp yet.

I want to cancel moving to the new phone and let WhatsApp run on the old phone.

However the old phone requires me to insert 6 numbers from my new phone and those 6 number is not available because WhatsApp haven't properly migrate.

I want to create another backup in my old phone and then do the move again/

It's very surprising and unexpected for WhatsApp to ask for encryption password AFTER I move to a new phone and can't back up.

They should have asked that in the beginning. If I forget I can just recreate another WhatsApp backup on the old phone.

I can't do that now and I am stuck in the middle

Or do I?

Answer (score 1):

Wow

I got my chat back.

How?

There are 2 ways.

On the old phone there is an option saying need help in getting the code. There's an option to use SMS instead. Use that and I am back to the old phone.

This is not how I did it.

What I did is to choose skip on the new phone.

Then I logged in again on my whatsapp on the old phone using the same number. They still store my chat on the phone it turns out.

Again I was asked for encryption password. I say I forget and they allow me to create another one by verifying my fingerprint.

So I got my whatsapp on the old phone complete with all the chat.

Hurray.........

Now that I know the enscryption password I can just move again more carefully.

I do think Whatsapp should have asked for the enscryption password before asking for 6 digit key. Like make sure your know your enscryption password before moving forward.

But they do think of the possibility when things go wrong like my situation and I am just happy my chats are back.